# Separate front audio panel in GNU/Linux

Tags: linux, audio, sound-card, front-panel

Is there a way to make the front audio panel act as a separate sound card in GNU/Linux?

I have a [motherboard](http://www.asus.com/Motherboard/P5BVM) with sound card that may be split into two logic sound cards (front panel and rear panel). It worked well under Windows XP with the software shipped together with this motherboard, but now I am trying to set up the similar configuration in GNU/Linux with no success so far. Thus my question: is it possible at all? And if it is, what is a correct way of doing this?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm having the same issue with the ASUS Sabertooth 990fx. The audio splitting works on Windows but I can't get it to work on Linux :(

Comment: @AreusAstarte No, unfortunately, I did not.

Comment: Thats unfortunate :( I now also went with buying a £5 USB audio card to use my headset. And well...it works under Windows. But it would have been great to actually use my 2 channel audio motherboard under Linux. To actually get away from Windows :p